# MySQL Trigger - INET_ATON before insert

Tags: mysql

I need to add INET_ATON  to ip field before insert

```
INSERT INTO (`id`,`ip`) VALUES (NULL,'127.0.0.1');
```

I need the database to convert ip transparently before insert.
and in select convert it back with INET_NTOA()

I **can not change the query** to use

```
INSERT INTO (`id`,`ip`) VALUES (NULL,INET_ATON('127.0.0.1'));
```

because i have no control over the software that executes those queries

Comment: updated your question to include the important relevant information you provided in a comment

Comment: What is data type of `ip` field?

Comment: I need data with int it's now varchar

Comment: working while remove "delimiter;" and I'm happy for your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the insert part you can setup a [`TRIGGER BEFORE INSERT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) in the database:

```
DELIMITER |
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `before_insert_ip`|
CREATE TRIGGER `before_insert_ip` BEFORE INSERT ON `table_name`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.`ip` = INET_ATON(NEW.`ip`);
END;
|
delimiter;
```

The SELECT part is a bit more tricky. There is no `AFTER SELECT` trigger in mysql which you could use to convert the IP back on the way into the application code.

Instead, you could RENAME the real table and hide it behind a [`VIEW`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html):

```
RENAME TABLE `table_name` TO `table_name_real`;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `table_name` (`id`, `ip`) AS
  SELECT `id`, INET_NTOA(`ip`) AS `ip` FROM `table_name_real`;
```

**Note:** when you use this `VIEW`, you need to modify the `TRIGGER` for the `INSERT` part to use `table_name_real` instead of `table_name`

Comment: But, AFAIK, that would break the `INSERT`. A `VIEW` is only insertable if it does not contain derived columns, which `INET_NTOA(`ip`)` is.

Comment: @Naltharial Yes you are right. I wasn't aware of that and tested it right now. Thanks for the correction. I have another idea and will come back to that later.

Comment: sorry sql error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.`ip` = INET_ATON(NEW.`ip`);

Comment: @user533178 i know .. fixed the syntax error in last edit. but what i describe there will not work. i'm too busy to describe the real solution now, please stand by :) i'll come back to it later.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `INSERT INTO  (`id`,`ip`) VALUES (NULL, INET_ATON('127.0.0.1'));` to insert in db

and to get back using `SELECT INET_NTOA(ip) FROM table`

Comment: this live project and I need to make it dynamic by trigger